# How to calculate spectrogram from nonstationary, nonuniformly sampled signal

Tags: matlab, frequency-spectrum, spectrogram, spatial, nonuniform

I have a high resolution 3D spatial signal (xy-elevation data collected via Terrestrial Laser Scan) with very nonuniform sampling (holes/shadows due to vegetation; point spread varies as a function of distance from scanner). The original point density varies from ~0-100 pt/cm2 and has been gridded/downsampled to 1 pt/cm2. Holes can be up to a few meters wide.

*I now need to calculate a 1D spatial spectrogram in Matlab (in either x or y vs elevation) without interpolating data over the holes or downsampling to the lowest sampling rate since these would introduce high frequency artifacts or decrease resolution* (I'm interested in the spectral characteristics at the cm-to-m-scale). The signal is also nonstationary, so I don't think I can just use a resampling or bootstrapping method.

The built-in Matlab functions I am familiar with (`FFT`, `spect`, `pwelch`,) result in NaN output if there are any NaNs in the signal, so I'm considering using Matlab's Lomb-Scargle periodogram algorith (`plomb`) in overlapping windows.

Is there another existing spectrogram method that uses least squares fitting, frequency-dependent windowing, or some other method to ignore NaNs/holes? Or is there any reason why using overlapping `plomb` windows would be a poor solution here?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Do you mean a 3D Terrestrial Laser Scan? 2D is pretty pointless (pun intended). Generally when you have $x$, $y$, and elevation data that is called 3D.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! Yes, I meant 3D TSL data (xyz). Please let me know if anything else needs to be clarified. Thank you!

Comment: Cool!  I've played a bit with that sort of data, so I wondered. :-)

Comment: Most things least squares often can also be formulated as $L_1$ and $L_{\infty}$ minimizations